# Service Oriented Architecture using WCF

Tags: wcf, soa

I worked with WCF services in our projects. We implemented most of the features as services in WCF and consumed from other projects which are web applications, desktop applications. Is this what SOA is ? Now I am getting some job oppurtunities who are looking for SOA developers, I am not sure if I can claim that I implemented SOA in the applications I developed. I read about SOA but could not get to a conclusion to my question. Can anybody explain me to clear my doubts ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst studying for the Microsoft 70-513 - Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Windows Communication Foundation, the term Service Orientated Architecture (SOA) is used quite often. The Microsoft book I have read states that;

> "The architectural principles behind an SOA is the ability to reuse
>   existing software assets wherever possible and to expose the
>   functionality of these assets as a set of services."

So if you have used WCF to implement services into your applications, then it would seem you have experience in working with SOA.

Comment: Fair statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding about Service Oriented Architecture

- We write WCF services which can be consumed by application written in
  various technologies Desktop, Phone or Web.So, that we don't have to
  write Service layer for each technology.
- Many times it happens that your core business logic remains same for 
  years but, your UI or Client changes form Desktop to Phone to
  Browser changes so, in this case you don't have to spend time again
  writing same thing.
- And as name it self say that it is service oriented so, if any
  application which is able to consume services your winner.